# Recording GNSS data with USRP N210

Tags: gps, labview, gnuradio, usrp, uhd

**I have no experience with using USRP as a front end to collect GNSS data.**

But from many GNSS journal publications that I have read, the USRP N210 is famously used as a good GNSS front end. Thus, my supervisor had just purchased N210s for his GNSS research team and instructed me to figure out how to use them as a GNSS front end.

**Can anyone tell me how I can collect GNSS/GPS data with it (i.e.** **how do I configure my host computer**)?

And what platform (**GNU Radio, NI LabView, MATLAB**, etc.) do people commonly use? **With said platforms, what should I configure?**

I currently have a **USRP N210** as well as an **OctoClock-G CDA-2990 (with GPSDO)** which I intend to use as a reference clock.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need a good frontend to record GNSS signals – as a matter of fact, many GNSS receivers use 4 bit (or even less) ADCs – simply because your quantization noise doesn't matter much if the SNR is < 1 anyway!

The N210 is still a good choice, because e.g. gnss-sdr works nicely out of the box with it.

So, read the gnss-sdr tutorial. What you want is literally the first thing they do in that tutorial.